# Verify refresh token belongs to a user [IdentityServer4]

Tags: identityserver4

I have a web application (SPA), when requesting logout the user passes both the access token and refresh token.

The logout endpoint is protected so the access token being revoked has to match what was authenticated.

However, how do I verify that the refresh token being requested to be revoked is one for that user or has a relationship in some way to that access token.

Note: When revoking an access token or refresh token I revoke specifically what is requested.

The end goal being to stop a malicious user from revoking a refresh token that belongs to someone else.

I understand the chances of that are remote but my question still stands.

Comment: If a malicious user manages to guess a refresh token then it should certainly be revoked.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I agree which is why created the question

Answer (score 0):

You could inject the [IRefreshTokenStore](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/44651bea9b02c992902639b21205f433aad47d03/src/Storage/src/Stores/IRefreshTokenStore.cs) into the class where your logout endpoint lives, retrieve the [refresh token](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/44651bea9b02c992902639b21205f433aad47d03/src/Storage/src/Models/RefreshToken.cs) using the IRefreshTokenStore's GetRefreshTokenAsync, then compare the subject in the refresh token with the subject in the verified access token.